Junction temperature of a switch mode power supply
Is the term 'maximum junction temperature' applicable to switch mode power supplies the way it is applied for linear regulators? If yes, what 'junction' usually it refers to for switch mode regulators? I was wondering because there would always be a 'maximum junction temperature' parameter in the datasheet of a linear regulator (e.g., LM78M05) but for some switch mode regulators (e.g.,DPBW06F-15) there are no such parameter mentioned in their datasheets.
Much appreciate your thoughts and comments.
Thank you.

A power supply (an assembly of many junctions, active components, and passives), no. A regulator (monolithic IC, lots of junctions integrated closely together), perhaps. Which one do you mean?

You can, may be think, in the light of two regulators I mentioned-DPBW06F-15 (SMPS), LM78M05( Linear). I do not have much information on the switch mode regulator other than its datasheet. But I guess, as you mentioned, it is an assembly of different type of components including semiconductor devices, so I don't know why the term 'junction temperature' is not relevant for a switch mode power supply.

Put simply: it has to be junctions temperature. But then, which one reaches the limit, and when? Surely a simpler method applies.

The data sheet tells you that the ambient temperature range it can handle is: -

This is the 50% rated-load temperature range. If you want the extended temperature range you have to derate the power capacity a tad more: -

There is no junction temperature to worry about because internally, the circuit is a hybrid design with protection circuits built in i.e. it's not a silicon IC (although it may contain one or two plus a MOSFET and a transformer). So, it's beyond the realm of where a single junction temperature is applicable or meaningful.

In the LM78M05 datasheet , in the functional block diagram (pg-8), I see many different types of semiconductor devices and the datasheet provides a single 'maximum junction temperature' representing all the semiconductor devices in the functional block diagram. Why can't the switch mode power supplies provide the a single 'max junction temperature' representing all the semiconductor devices it is using in its circuit? Is it because they are all different discrete devices from different manufacturers?

@Bee16 the 7805 will have all the transistors etched onto one piece of silicon and will therefore have an almost common junction temperature across all transistors. The Meanwell device is a hybrid design and this means different parts from different suppliers all brought together but, they can't share the same die because they should be seen as discrete devices.

Further to Andy's answer: in the context of a power supply assembly (be it a module, or a silver-box), the maximum junction temperatures (note plural) are strictly the concern of the product designers.
As part of the power supply design process, the supply will be operated under a variety of input, output and environmental conditions and the temperatures of the key semiconductor devices (bridge rectifier, power diodes, MOSFETs, driver ICs, etc.) will be measured. The maximum junction temperatures will be extrapolated from the measurements and all devices will be verified to be within their SOAs (safe operating areas).
Overload / stress tests are also performed, by doing things like overloading the power supply, blocking the fans etc. to understand which components may fail and what the failure modes might be. Part of this often involves temperature measurements of known 'hot' devices. Safety testing also does these types of measurements, but just to ensure that the device fails safely (and is less concerned with things like thermal margins).
If you operate the device within its specified limits, the designer has (hopefully) done the due-diligence to ensure that no devices contained within the enclosure are escaping their SOAs. Hence it's not your concern.

Thank you, that is very helpful as my final goal was to make sure I am operating the converters in a safe way as to not overheat the modules themselves. Your comment assures me that if the operational temperature doesn't rise above the range Meanwell listed in their datasheet I should be fine.
